# UIBezierPath not drawing when I override drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw something here in my UIView subclass but when I add it as a subview it just shows a black view. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* shape5Color = [UIColor redColor];

    //// Shape 5 Drawing
    UIBezierPath* shape5Path = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [shape5Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(54.99, 118)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(460.01, 118)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(460.01, 355)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(383.75, 355)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(363.26, 327.94)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(433, 327.94)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(433, 145)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(84, 144.96)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(84, 327.94)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(152.62, 327.94)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(133, 355)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(54.99, 355)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(54.99, 118)];
    [shape5Path closePath];
    [shape5Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(257, 223.5)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(394.27, 404)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(119.73, 404)];
    [shape5Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(257, 223.5)];
    [shape5Path closePath];

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat sx = 179.0 / shape5Path.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat sy = 179.0 / shape5Path.bounds.size.height;

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, sx, sy);
    [shape5Color setFill];
    [shape5Path fill];
}
```

I tried setting the view's background to clearColor but that didn't work.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: [super drawRect:rect] ?

Comment: Nope, I don't believe that's necessary. From the docs: If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in drawRect and make sure that its being called - perhaps setNeedsDisplay needs to be called for the view.

Comment: What's your view's frame size?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde Forgot to update this, but yep my frame size was completely wrong.